# Understanding Blum Blum Shub algorithm. (Python implementation)

Tags: python, algorithm, cryptography

Please help me to understand BBS algorithm. I did this implementation:

```
class EmptySequenseError(Exception):                                  
    pass                                                              


class BlumBlumShub(object):                                           
    def __init__(self, length):                                       
        self.length = length                                          
        self.primes = e(1000)  # Primes obtained by my own Sieve of Eratosthenes implementation.                                                                            

    def get_primes(self):                                             
        out_primes = []                                               
        while len(out_primes) < 2:                                    
            curr_prime = self.primes.pop()          
            if curr_prime % 4 == 3:                                   
                out_primes.append(curr_prime)                         
        return out_primes                                             

    def set_random_sequence(self):                                    
        p, q = self.get_primes()                                      
        m = p * q                                                     
        self.random_sequence = [((x+1)**2)%m for x in range(self.length)]

    def get_random_sequence(self):                                    
        if self.random_sequence:                                      
           return self.random_sequence                               
        raise EmptySequenseError("Set random sequence before get it!")
```

And I have several questions. At first I do not want to use `random` library, it is too naive. My sequence is increasing, it is not absolutely random. **How to prevent increasing in returned sequence?** And I do not understand this part of the algorithm description:

> At each step of the algorithm, some output is derived from *x<sub>n+1</sub>*; the output is commonly either the bit parity of *x<sub>n+1</sub>* or one or more of the least significant bits of *x<sub>n+1</sub>*.

**Please explain to me what does it mean?**

#### Edit summary:

- The algorithm is corrected.
- Quote substituted to en.wikipedia quote.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
    for x in range(self.length):                                  
        self.random_sequence.append((x ** 2) % m)
```

Just generates `[(x ** 2) % m for x in range(self.length)]`, which is roughly x<sub>n+1</sub> = n<sup>2</sup> mod M.

The algorithm is *supposed* to be: x<sub>n+1</sub> = x<sub>n</sub><sup>2</sup> mod M

Do you see where your version is different?

---

As for the quote - you don't say where it's from, but [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blum_Blum_Shub) has:

> At each step of the algorithm, some output is derived from *x<sub>n+1</sub>*; the output is commonly either the bit parity of *x<sub>n+1</sub>* or one or more of the least significant bits of *x<sub>n+1</sub>*.

It means that *x<sub>n+1</sub>* is the *seed* for the next iteration, but *not* the pseudo-random number returned. Instead, the return value is derived from  *x<sub>n+1</sub>* by counting its bit parity (this yields either 0 or 1 each iteration), or by taking only some number of top bits.

Comment: I still can't get, what should I return? Is parity bit means http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_bit ? Should I return `((x+1)**2) % m` or something else? Or what the bitwise operation should be done?

Comment: bit parity the even/odd quality of the number of 1's in the bit string.  in python, that's basically: `parity_of_x = bin(x).count(1) % 2`

Answer (score 3):

Blum Blum Shub is described in [Chapter Five](http://cacr.uwaterloo.ca/hac/about/chap5.pdf) of the Handbook of Applied Cryptography, Section 5.5.2.  There is a lot of helpful stuff about random number generation in that chapter.

Answer (score 2):

I would rather formalize my understanding as an answer.

```
class BlumBlumShub(object):                                             
    def __init__(self, length):                                         
        self.length = length                                            
        self.primes = e(1000)                                           

    def gen_primes(self):                                               
        out_primes = []                                                 
        while len(out_primes) < 2:                                      
            curr_prime = self.primes[random.randrange(len(self.primes))]
            if curr_prime % 4 == 3:                                     
                out_primes.append(curr_prime)                           
        return out_primes                                               

    def random_generator(self):                                         
        x = random.randrange(1000000)                                   
        while self.length:                                              
            x += 1                                                      
            p, q = self.gen_primes()                                    
            m = p * q                                                   
            z = (x**2) % m                                              
            self.length -= 1                                            
            yield str(bin(z).count('1') % 2)                            

    def get_random_bits(self):                                          
        return ''.join(self.random_generator())
```

- BBS is pseudorandom *bit* generator, it must return random bits, not integers.
- Return value is just parity bit of result x<sub>n+1</sub><sup>2</sup> % m operation.

If I wrongly understood something, please explain my mistakes.